# How to parallelize loops with Java 8's Fork/Join framework

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, fork-join

How to parallelize loops with Java 8's Fork/Join framework. Accually I did not work with multiple threading . I read lots of question in SO .Now i am unable to implement the parallel processing of list in Java 8. Any one can help me ?

I have tried somthing like from [this link](http://www.omsn.de/blog/how-to-parallelize-loops-with-java-7-fork-join-framework).

```
routes.stream().parallel().forEach(this::doSomething);
```

Scenario like list based on routes list I need to devide the task and execute I need like insted of foreach loop I want parallel execution of based on array size.

My problem is when  processing  the `updateSchedules`  service it is taking too much time. That is the reason I want to implement the threading concept here. `scheduleService.updateSchedules(originId, destinationId,req.getJourneyDate());`

```
for (Availabilities ar : routes) {
  try {
    log.info("Starting for bus" + ar);
    Bus bus = new Bus();

    // Get schedule list
    BitlaSchedules schedule = scheduleRepo
      .findByOriginIdAndDestinationIdAndScheduleIdAndTravelIdAndRouteId(originId, 
         destinationId, ar.getScheduleId(), ar.getTravelId(), ar.getRouteId());

    if (schedule == null) {
      scheduleService.updateSchedules(originId, destinationId,req.getJourneyDate());
      schedule = scheduleRepo
        .findByOriginIdAndDestinationIdAndScheduleIdAndTravelIdAndRouteId(originId, 
          destinationId, ar.getScheduleId(), ar.getTravelId(), ar.getRouteId());
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess using an Executor would be more appropriate. How did you come to the conclusion Fork/Join is what you need?

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what you've tried (not just "some things from...") and what specific problem you've encountered. If it's a compiler error, copy/paste the error. If it's a runtime error, do the same. If it's unexpected behaviour, describe it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @sitansu I see no description of the problem you've encountered. Your code is not indented, and seems to have nothing to do with parallelisation.

Comment: @slim Updated my question Please check again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fdreger already said, it will only help you with CPU intensive tasks.
So before making any assumptions WHY something should be run parallel to gain performance, do yourself a favor and profile. Most of the time the bottleneck is IO related.

I will give you a very simple example how you could use parallel streams in java.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // some dummy data
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) list.add(i);

        // to simulate some CPU intensive work
        Random random = new SecureRandom();

        List<String> result = list.parallelStream().map(i -> {

            // simulate work load
            int millis = 0;
            try {
                millis = random.nextInt(1000);
                Thread.sleep(millis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            // return any desired result
            return "Done something with " + i + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " took " + millis + "ms";
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect joins - will return once all the workers are done

        // print the result
        result.forEach(System.out::println);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably the basic error is that you are trying to do it.

Don't! The fork/join framework is a *very* specific piece of engineering - which solves a very specific area:
 - solving CPU intensive problems;
 - that can be split without sharing resources (i.e. no synchronization or locking between ).

Your code seems to use an external service:
 - if the service uses database of any kind, then your problem is not CPU intensive;
 - even if not, then - since there is an obvious `update`, then there is a shared, mutable state that requires synchronization (especially since we seem to have multiple writers).

This means that you **gain nothing** by using the parallel stream.

Just use a standard executor with a thread pool and submit your items as tasks.

Comment: @Sitansu Any up-to-date Java book will explain executors, as will the standard Java tutorials, or hundreds of pages you can find by Googling.